# IFileOpenDialog gives error "Location is not available" and fails to load user libraries on windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

Experiencing the same issue as this:
[CoCreateInstance issue on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688624/cocreateinstance-issue-on-windows-7)
{Basically using the IFileOpenDialog sometimes gives the error:  "Location is not available" "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop refers to a location that is unavailable". The user can continue after this message shows but the libraries do not show the contents correctly and it is rather annoying.}

The code is being called in an MFC application running with user permissions, but the issue only happens intermittently on at least 3 test systems.

Here is the code for the creation of the dialog and showing it:

```
    IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(FileOpenDialog), NULL, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFileOpen));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DWORD dwFlags = 0;

        pFileOpen->GetOptions ( &dwFlags );
        pFileOpen->SetOptions ( dwFlags | FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT | FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST | FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM );

        pFileOpen->SetTitle ( L"Select file for upload" );

        hr = pFileOpen->Show(this->GetSafeHwnd());

        //everything after this for retrieving files selected works fine.
```

Comment: It is the same issue.  And just as unanswerable.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I need to find a way to make it stop so I'm hoping someone out there has an answer. The other possibility I'm thinking about is using the FOS_HIDEPINNEDPLACES flag and then manually adding back in some shortcuts to C:, network, the users folder, etc and hoping it eliminates the problem.